# Get all input in div for ajax request

Tags: jquery, forms, post

I am trying to get all input textboxes, radio groups, checkboxes etc. I am having trouble getting the selected radio and checkboxs values, I cant figure it out.

I can get the text boxes but can't seem to get the "selected" in the right place. At the moment it just gets the first value for radio/checkboxes not the selected value.

```
$('#form_1 input').each(function(key)               
    formData += '&'+$('#'+this.id).attr('name')+'='+$('#'+this.id).val();   
});
```

Thanks

**EDITED**

```
$('#form_1 input').each(function(key, value) {              
    if ((this.type === "radio" || this.type === "checkbox") && this.checked === true) {
         val = this.value;
    } else {
         val = this.value;
    }

    alert($('#'+this.id).attr('name') + ' = ' + val);
    formData += '&'+$('#'+this.id).attr('name')+'='+val;    
});
```

Ok now I get every value for radios etc so I am a step closer. Just need to get the values of selected radios now.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var val;
if (this.type === "radio" || this.type === "checkbox") {
     val = this.checked;
} else {
     val = this.value;
}
```

For radios and check boxes you care about the checked attribute.

**Update**

You wrote

`(this.type === "radio" || (this.type === "checkbox" && this.checked === true))`

You meant

`((this.type === "radio" || this.type === "checkbox") && this.checked === true)`

You need those brackets in the right place.

**Further edit**

The logic was a bit broken.

Basically what you want.

```
if ((this.type === "radio" || this.type === "checkbox") && this.checked === false) {
    return;
}
```

This means if its a non-checked radio/checkbox you do nothing.

Comment: @Raynos - Thanks for the help. The radio values are of value to me so how do I get the selected value?

Comment: @Jon you can call `.checked` to see whether they are checked. Then call `.value` to get the value of the checked item.

Comment: @Raynos - I have edited it but am a bit of a newb so dont know where to edit. I have edited my original post to what I have now, which gets radio all values instead of only the selected radios. Thanks so far.

Comment: @Raynos - Thanks again. I have edited like you said but still no luck. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the [`serialize()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

It will take care of getting the values of the selected elements for you.

```
var formData = $('#form_1').serialize();
```

**From the docs:**

> The .serialize() method can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form elements, such as , , and . However, it is typically easier to select the  tag itself for serialization:
>
> ```
> $('form').submit(function() {
>   alert($(this).serialize());
>   return false;
> });
> ```
>
> This produces a standard-looking query string:
>
> ```
> a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5
> ```

Comment: `.serialize` is actaully superior. Oh btw how was your 2 month holiday ;)

Comment: @Raynos: Much more productive! :o) Couldn't stay away though. Your rep was getting a little too high. ;o)

Comment: @patrickdw Why did you come back! SO is an addictive curse ;)

Comment: @Raynos: It is terribly addictive. I guess I just missed pretending like I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @patrickdw That's a secret, your not supposed to tell all the question askers we don't actually know what were talking about!

Comment: @patrick dw - I wanted to use serialize() but it is part of a bigger form and just want to validate accounts in the div as they are added to the form.

Comment: @Raynos: Cat's out of the bag now. I might as well come clean and admit that all my answers are just cut-n-paste from W3Schools!

Comment: @Jon: You can run `serialize()` against individual or groups of elements. You can use the `$(':input')` custom selector to get all the types of form input elements.

Comment: @patrickdw ;_; If I see this answer on W3Schools im downvoting you.

Comment: @Raynos: That's alright. I'll get it all back just by recommending jQuery for everything. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly but it looks like you're trying achieve something that's already available - you might want to check out [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) - use it as `var formData = $('#form_1').serialize()`